# Button not showing up in FrameLayout - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

Here's my code - this is a screen that shows a camera preview.  I want to have 2 buttons on it, a full screen one that takes a picture and another button on top of that opens the menu.  The SDK I'm targeting is 16 so I don't want anything not compatible with that.

According to the Android Website: Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

Thus, the ImageButton, which is the last item in my FrameLayout should show up on top.  In the Design window of android studio, everything looks perfect.  But when I run it on my phone, the ImageButton does not show up.  Why is that?

I've already tried including this in my onCreate but it did not help:

```
            ImageButton menuButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mainMenuButtonID);
            menuButton.bringToFront();
```

Here's the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/cameraLayoutID"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

/** Stuff on top should come last in FrameLayout **/

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceViewID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/takePictureButtonID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00ffffff" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/mainMenuButtonID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_white_48dp" />

 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Right...are you sure there isn't anything wrong with the `"@drawable/ic_menu_white_48dp"` (since `ImageButton` is `wrap_content`/`wrap_content`). Also, might be a Instant Run related bug.

Comment: @user framelayout can be used in the following scene: u have 2 layout and u want one to be above another. For your case you can put both the button in one layout and then run. it should work!

Comment: @Shaishav yes I tried using the ic_launcher image and it does not work either

Comment: @Smit  well I want the ImageButton to be on top of the Button so should I create another FrameLayout that only includes the Button and then a RelativeLayout that includes the ImageButton?

Comment: @user145190 definitely! that should do the job!

Comment: @smit that didn't work :(

Comment: @user145190 did you remove the imageButton thing from the code ?

Comment: @smit yes I removed the ImageButton from the java code.  I've tried several combinations in the XML now and none work.  My most recent one was to include both buttons in their own relative layouts...

Comment: @user145190 true. I tried all the prespects but none sounds to work? why not try to put image as a background for button ?

Comment: framelayout will add one over other. So the last added will be at the top so on